# Pyqt5 on Windows(duplicates the main window when starting the process)

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, multiprocessing

Всем привет, не смог найти ответа на вопрос. Проблема заключается в следующем:
1) Есть приложение на Windows, gui на pyqt5

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QTextBrowser


class my_process(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        self.queue.put('run')


class my_thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, window, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.queue.get()
            if command == "run":
                self.window.my_signal.emit("из IDE при клике на кнопку на экране появляется этот текст")
            # После сборки при нажатии на кнопку появляется еще одно окно приложения
            # ссылка на собранное приложение https://yadi.sk/d/HZqdZ8Eo16q3bw


class test_multicore(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        # описание интерфейса#######################
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Qthreads and multicore')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.testButton = QPushButton("test")
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.test)
        self.command_window = QTextBrowser()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.command_window)
        ##########################################
        # Сигнал для вывода на экран
        self.my_signal.connect(self.my_slot)

        self.queue = Queue()
        self.my_thread = my_thread(self, self.queue)
        self.my_thread.start()

    my_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def my_slot(self, text):
        self.command_window.append(text)

    def test(self):
        self.my_process = my_process(self.queue)
        self.my_process.daemon = False
        self.my_process.start()


# pyinstaller --onedir  probe.py   команда для сборки приложения

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = test_multicore()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Суть проблемы : Когда я запускаю этот код из IDE всё работает как надо. Но если я собираю проект с помощью Pyinstaller, при запуске нового процесса(при клике на кнопку), моё основное окно дублируется и то что должно было происходить в самом процессе не выполняется. Я думаю что проблема в том что для процессов не задано имя, и он берет имя основного окна, но как это исправить не придумал. Прошу Вашей помощи!

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: вечером смогу набросать такой пример, если конечно до вечера не найдется человек который сталкивался с такой проблемой и решил ее:)

Comment: Добавил прототип программы, проблема воспроизводится 1 в 1, добавил ссылку на собранное приложение, и команду которой собирал

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support

добавил после запуска программы строчку freeze_support() и проблема решилась

```
freeze_support()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = test_multicore()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```